# Undo/redo functionality

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, workflow

I use lock to cursor, but sometimes camera go crazy and i cannot see anything. So this happened and i dunno how to see. Pressed ctrl+z a lot of times, did some manipulations with camera and object in outliner and viewport windows to see mesh. Then finally see my mesh, but it was too far from what i made(pressed undo a lot, ha), close to very beginning. And because of some thing a made in outliner and in viewport to see mesh again, my redo/undo history rewrited and i cannot go redo to point when i've got camera issue. So, is there any way to recover? Autosave is too far too

Answer (score 0):

Hold down shift + s and select cursor to center. Then again shift + s and select selected to cursor. Your object will now got to the center. reference pics below:

[image: before lost:]
[image: now messed up.]
[image: cursor to center]
[image: selected to cursor]